# Relation between source terms and interactions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, interactions

I am reading the books by A. Zee and Peskin/Schroeder and in both I encountered a so called "source term" $J$, which is added to the Lagrangian as

$$L(\phi) = L_{free}(\phi) + \phi(x) J(x).$$

For the sake of simplicity let's stick to a scalar field $\phi(x)$. I found out that $J$ can be interpreted as a source, e.g. in electrodynamics as the vector potential. I am also aware that it is often just used in a generic way to find the $n$-point functions.

What I am asking myself is what the connection between general **interactions** and the **source** term $J$ is. Are they *equivalent* in a sense that $J=0$ means no interaction / free theory, while a nonvanishing $J$ yields interactions? I could think of $J=\phi(x)^2$ for instance. Then we would recover the the $\phi^3$-theory! So, is $J\neq 0$ nothing else than an interacting theory?

Comment: I highly recommend the section on generating functionals in 'QFT for the Gifted Amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell.  Look online. Plenty of examples of the different approaches to the same result of describing interactions.